# How to control step definition file cucumber annotation only applicable to one step definition file?

Tags: cucumber, tdd, bdd

I am trying to run two step definition files(cucumber) simultaneously in that I applied @Before annotation in one step definition file. While i am running these, annotation is applying to both and giving the result. How can i stop or control annotation is applicable to only one step definition file?

Comment: you mean applying @before for only one feature/scenario not for all the features/scenarios?

Comment: thanks for your reply..supputuri, yes. i am applaying only one scenario that should apply only one step defination file ..but it is applaying both step defination file..and two step defination files are in same packge only.

Comment: Hello @MADHUkandukuri, your question is not that clear. Could you please be more specific about what you are looking for? how did you apply a tag on step definitions? Feature files have scenarios and step definitions file will have their implementation.

Comment: sorry..for confusion..i am applaying @Before annotation in step defination file to a method in first step defination file. and i am running two step def file at a time. here pblm is Before annotation is applaying second step def file methods also..so how can i control this..? so that it is only applicable to fist step def only

Comment: Which language are you writing your step definitions in?

Comment: Java language, @Greg

Answer (score 1):

All step definition files are parsed when Cucumber starts executing. Cucumber then uses the scenarios in your feature files to determine which step definitions to call. There is no concept of "running a step definition file".

A `Before` hook will run before each Scenario that Cucumber executes. It makes no difference which feature file the scenario is written in or which step definition file the hook is defined in.

You may want to consider [using a `Background` instead](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background), especially if a non-technical reader of the feature file would find the behaviours it describes important. A `Background` runs before each scenario written in the same feature file.

Alternatively, you might accomplish what you want by using [conditional (or tagged) hooks](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#conditional-hooks). A conditional `Before` hook will only be run if the scenario has tags that satisfy the hook's tag expression.